# How to match number saved in contactlist with incoming call number

Tags: android

Hi friends i am trying to make a project in which i am matching the incoming call number with the diffrent formats of numbers that are saved in diffrent phones.
I am able to match "+919045308261" and "+91 90 45 308261" but i want that the matching must work on another formats also.What must i do so that it work over another formats also??.. 
The code that i have used is..

```
package com.example.matchnumbers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String incomingcall = "+919045308261";
    String str = "+91 90 45 308261";
    String st1 = "0 90 45 308261";
    String str2 = "90 45 308261";
    String str3="9045308261";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        str = str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        if(incomingcall.equals(str)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hit occurs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: use [PhoneNumberUtils.compare()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)...

Comment: @GopalRao hi you met after a long time,how are you???
n Thanks for your answer you always help me alot

Comment: it seems you are busy ok whenever you get free kindly look over this thing please....
 boolean a= PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number,phoneNumber);
                  if(a){
                   
       String contname = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
         .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
       if(!contname.equals(null)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tts.speak(contname+" calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        
       }
      }
      
I am getting the contactname tosat but the problem is it is not speaking contactname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this help you:

Buddy you can make use of `ContentProvider`(For Comparing PhoneNo with Contacts)

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode("PhoneNo"));

String name = null;
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
                    new String[] { Phones.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
    cursor.close();
}
```

Above code will match the Phone number in contact list and will return you the Contact Name if the Phone no is stored in Contacts...

**OR if you have two string and you want to compare them:**

```
String phone1;   
String phone2; 

 if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(phone1, phone2)) {
      // code if both are same
   }
```